# How do I use LastWriteTime when comparing files in different folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

This script compare FILE objects by `Name`, `Length`, and `LastWriteTime`.

```
cls
$Source= "C:\Source"
$Destination = "C:\Destination"                  

Compare-Object (ls $Source) (ls $Destination) -Property Name, Length, LastWriteTime | Sort-Object {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending
```

Output:

```
Name                 Length LastWriteTime          SideIndicator
----                 ------ -------------          -------------
11.0.3127.0.txt           6 8/31/2013 10:01:19 PM  <=
11031270.txt              0 8/31/2013 9:43:41 PM   <=
11.0.3128.0.txt          13 8/31/20131:20:15PM     =>
11.0.3129.0.txt           0 8/28/2013 11:34:38 AM  <=
```

I need to create a script that retrive the current DB version and checks if single or multiple patches are available.

The way it works is the following:

1. Run a SQL Query against a DB
2. Store the SQL Info onto a fileName (eg.11.0.3128.0.txt) on C:\Destination
3. Compare the information in the .txt file against the files/patches present in the *Source folder*
4. List item
5. If *Source folder* contains older files/patches  -- do nothing
6. If *Source folder* contain newer files, then copy those files to C:\NewPatchFolder
7. Then run a script to apply all the new patches

I already took care of #1, #2. I was planning to modify/add on to above script to simplify the steps in #3, #4 and #5.

Is it possible to modify above script to achive my goals as follow:

- compare LastWriteTime from the files in C:\Source folder with the file in C:\Destination
- copies the files in C:\Source folder to C:\NewPatchFolder if LastWriteTime is equal or greater  then the LastWriteTime of the file on the C:\Destination folder

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `Compare-Object` for this. Try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem $Source | % {
  $f = Join-Path $Destination $_.Name
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $f) {
    if ($_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Item $f).LastWriteTime) {
      Move-Item $_.FullName 'C:\NewPatchFolder'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you for the answer...  

I ended up figuring another  working solution:

$Source = Get-ChildItem "C:\Source" 

$T = (dir C:\Destination | select LastWriteTime -Last 1).lastwritetime
 dir | ?{$_.creationtime -ge $T -and !$_.PSiscontainer}

 
 foreach ($i in  $Source)
 {
     if ($i.CreationTime -ge $T)
      
     {
         Copy-Item $i.FullName C:\NewPatchFolder
     }
 }

Comment: @Tony Please don't post code in comments as that tends to be unreadable. If you found another solution you're going with, you should post that as an answer and accept it. Note that your code does not match the requirements you outlined, though, and also may not work as you expect. `$T` is assigned the `LastWriteTime` of the last file listed in `C:\Destination`, which isn't guaranteed to be the most (or least) recent file.